# What does "download and install 32-bit jetbrains runtime" actually do in IDE GoLand?

Tags: go, goland

I'm a newbie,today I'm try to install GoLand.

It has a choice called "Download and install 32-bit Jetbrains Runtime".The image:
[image]

I deselect and install it but I also could run my first `hello world` successfully.I try to search it in Google but nothing found.

System: Windows 10, 64-bit.(I think it might have the connection with `Java` but not sure.).Could someone tell me what it is?Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That is useful only if you need to install the JVM for 32 bit. Since you are running on a 64 bit machine, ignore it and use the IDE as is.

Comment: Just curious.What does it do on a 32-bit device?64 bit machine could also install 32 bit JVM.

Comment: It's preferable to use a native 64 bit app, whenever possible, and the JVM makes no exception. But there may be cases/limitations/restrictions when a 32bit JVM is required or our support team might need to ask you to use it. Until that happens, use the 64bit version (default, don't check the option there).